# How can I map `Ctrl+Alt+Char` and `Ctrl+Number` in vim on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, vi

## 1.Enviroment

Env: vim+zsh+iTerm2 on Mac OSX 10.9.2. (Same problems in macvim on Mac OSX 10.9.2)

## 2. Mapping Problem

In mac, mappings for `<A-char>` won't directly work in mac.

```
:inoremap <A-u> type some string A-u
:inoremap <A-p> type some string A-p
:inoremap
i  õ           * type some string A-u
i  ð           * type some string A-p
```

As far as I know about `<A-char>` in mac, hit `<A-u>` will print nothing but with a sound alert. hit `<A-p>` will print `π`. I found that map for `π` works well.

```
:inoremap π type some string A-p
```

Is it possible to map `<A-u>` in vim? Yes!
Let me  go into  this problem deeply:

```
:map <A-S-p> not work
:map ∏ works well(A-S-p will print `∏`)

:map <C-A-p> not work
:map <C-π> still not work

:map <C-S-p> do work
:map <C-1> not work
```

**So , is it possible to map `Ctrl-Alt-char` and `Ctrl+Number`?**

---

Of course, you can use fastcodes in vimfastcodes in vim. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606892/vim-keyboard-mapping-problems-in-mac/23608928#23608928

Answer (score 2):

If you use MacVim, the easiest way is:

```
set macmeta
```

So that MacVim will treat alt/option as Meta key, you can then bind:

```
nmap <C-M-S> :call foo_func()
```

The keys pressed for above is: Ctrl+alt+s.

Hope this helps and solves your issue, happy Vimming!

Comment: It only works in macvim.app, not work in macvim's terminal vertion.

Comment: You can override sys default vim with:
brew install macvim --override-system-vim